# How change file loading from "URL" to "app local" in android?

Tags: android, json, mp3, local

There is an android app that works fine when built in android studio, it loads playlist files from URL. I changed that to mp3 file and worked. I just want to put these mp3 files inside the application so user won't need to download them from web. I found the related code in json file :

```
{
    "type": "illustration",
    "title": "The Kindness of Strangers",
    "author": "A. Gencheva",
    "cover": "https://content.emporium.bendingspoons.com/assets/com.bendingspoonsapps.SleepHelp/f98a1298e4958e544a8b4728dcf63cdda2c9ee54.jpg",
    "story_category": "story_category_fiction",
    "playlist": "https://content.emporium.bendingspoons.com/assets/com.bendingspoonsapps.SleepHelp/07de365db486d57b9d5dbff3dafedce541a2a127.m3u8",
    "has_start": false,
    "is_premium": true,
    "is_new": false,
    "duration": 817.55,
    "_id": "5d5d218cb5173700367a9a08"
},
```

I putted x.mp3 file in root, in app folder, in raw folder, ... and tried to change "playlist" value to x.mp3, /x.mp3, ...

Can you guide me to do this modification please?

Thank you for your time

Comment: What kind of related code did you find in thet json file?

Comment: The code that I shared. It's for one of the items, there are 9 more like this but all pointing to a web URL. I want to include these mp3 files in my app, like in assets or raw folder.

Answer (score 0):

First put all audios in ProjectRoot/app/assets folder

Then create uri from asset like

```
 Uri soundUrl = Uri.fromFile(new File("//android_asset/mymusicfile.mp3"));
```

Pass this uri to media player

Comment: Thank you, can you explain a little more? where should I add this code? and for every6 mp3 file I have to create a variable like soundUrl? Then can I call it from json? THNX

Comment: You can create a function where you pass the filename and it'll return the uri, then you can pass uri to mediaplayer or exoplayer. In case of exoplayer, something like MediaItem.from(uri) might work

Comment: These are M3u8PlayerActivity.tk AND SleepStoriesActivity.tk , I'm more a designer I don't know what to change so player loads included files instead from web.

M3u8PlayerActivity.tk https://paste.ee/p/bD2No

SleepStoriesActivity.tk https://paste.ee/p/W1C9h

MainActivity.tk https://paste.ee/p/PRujZ

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are M3u8PlayerActivity.tk AND SleepStoriesActivity.tk , I'm more a designer I don't know what to change so player loads included files instead from web.

M3u8PlayerActivity.tk
https://paste.ee/p/bD2No

SleepStoriesActivity.tk
https://paste.ee/p/W1C9h

MainActivity.tk
https://paste.ee/p/PRujZ

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question if a new information has to be added. Doing so through the answer section is not supposed.